# How do I get the fields of a user object

Tags: 6

I want to know all the fields of the object returned by `user_load()`.

I can analyze it while the site is running with `var_dump()`, but I want to see the fields without running Drupal, say by opening any (.module) files.

In general, how can I see the object fields of standard objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The full answer is: There's no single piece of code which can answer your question. Since PHP has weak and dynamic typing, any piece of code can access the global $user object and can remove/add something to the the object (whether this is always a good idea is an other question).

As a Java (which statically and strong typed) veteran this was the biggest difference to cope with.

BTW: Use dpm which comes with [krumo](http://krumo.sourceforge.net/) support instead of var_dump this makes the output much more readable. An other aproach is to get familiar with a debugger (Xdebug or Zend).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look in your "users" table; the function returns all the columns of that table.

Comment: I support this answer, although as pointed out by BetaRide, more data may be added, for example, by the profile module which is there just for that purpose.